# Using Seaborn, how do I get all the elements from a pointplot to appear above the elements of a violoinplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, z-order

Using Seaborn 0.6.0, I am trying to overlay a `pointplot` on a `violinplot`. My problem is that the 'sticks' from the individual observations of the `violinplot` are plotted on top of the markers from `pointplot` as you can see below.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=[12,8])
sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips,
               split=True, inner='stick', ax=ax, palette=['white']*2)
sns.pointplot(x="day", y='total_bill', hue="smoker",
                   data=tips, dodge=0.3, ax=ax, join=False)
```

[image]

Looking closely at this figure, it appears as the green errorbar is plotted above the violoin sticks (look at Saturday), but the blue error bars, and the blue and green dots are plotted underneath the violin sticks.

I have tried passing different combinations of `zorder` to both functions, but that did not ameliorate the plot appearance. Is there anything I can do to get all the elements from the pointplot to appear above all the elements of the violoinplot?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Similar to Diziet Asahi's answer, but a little bit more straightforward. Since we're setting the zorder, we don't need to draw the plots in the order we want them to appear, which saves the trouble of sorting the artists. I'm also making it so that the pointplot doesn't appear in the legend, where it is not useful.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matploltlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

ax = sns.pointplot(x="day", y='total_bill', hue="smoker",
              data=tips, dodge=0.3, join=False, palette=['white'])
plt.setp(ax.lines, zorder=100)
plt.setp(ax.collections, zorder=100, label="")

sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips,
               split=True, inner='stick', ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: `get_children` returns all of the artists included in the `Axes` draw tree, including the ticks, labels, etc (not all of which participate in the zorder sorting) but this can have surprising side effects.

Comment: Ah, ok. With the darkgrid style, all the grid lines are well behaved, at least.

Comment: It's super sad that there is no "`legend=False`" keyword in pointplot.

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit hack-ish, I'm sure someone else will have a better solution. Notice that I have changed your colors to improve the contrast between the two plots

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=[12,8])
sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips,
               split=True, inner='stick', ax=ax)
a = list(ax.get_children()) # gets the artists created by violinplot
sns.pointplot(x="day", y='total_bill', hue="smoker",
                   data=tips, dodge=0.3, ax=ax, join=False, palette=['white'])
b = list(ax.get_children()) # gets the artists created by violinplot+pointplot

# get only the artists in `b` that are not in `a`
c = set(b)-set(a)
for d in c:
    d.set_zorder(1000) # set a-order to a high value to be sure they are on top
```

[image]

EDIT: following @tcaswell 's comment, I also propose this other solution (create 2 Axes, one for each type of plot). Notice however, that if you're going to route, you'll have to rework the legend, since they end up superimposed in the present example.

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[12,8])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips,
               split=True, inner='stick', ax=ax1)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111, frameon=False, sharex=ax1, sharey=ax1)
sns.pointplot(x="day", y='total_bill', hue="smoker",
                   data=tips, dodge=0.3, ax=ax2, join=False, palette=['white'])
ax2.set_xlabel('')
ax2.set_ylabel('')
```

[image]

Comment: There should be a way to ask the returned objects from the seaborn calls what new artists it created so you don't have to do that `set` logic.  If there isn't I am going to passively aggressively ask you to report that as a bug against seaborn ;)

Comment: @tcaswell unfortunately, these seaborn calls return the Axes instance, and since both calls act on the same Axes, the second call adds on its artists to the first. I guess a simpler way to do this would be to create a second subplot (whith sharex and sharey) on top of the first one, and to the `sns.pointplot` using that Axes. That way, both plots and their artists would be nicely separated

Comment: @DizietAsahi: The idea of using sets works like a charm, but I am curious: do you know if there is another more direct way to get the children of seaborn plots?

Comment: Did you ever report the seaborn bug that @tacaswell proposed?  I'm running into this now.